# Laptop won't boot after charging while turned off.

Tags: windows-8

I tried to charge my laptop while off and then it won't boot. when I try turning up.. Nothing happens when I press turn on button... Once I connect charger it indicates charging.

Comment: Which manufacturer ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Charge your battery before attempting to turn on your laptop.
2. If that did not help. Remove the battery and power cable then hold the power button down for about 30 seconds, insert the battery and try turning it on now.